# Save data in android to use after update

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences, updates, reinstall

I want to save an `int` and a `boolean` in my android-app. At the moment I use `sharedPreferences` to save the variables. What happens if I update my app or reinstall it?

Should I better use a database for saving the variables?

Comment: you can use file also to store the values. Store the file on external storage and access it later

Comment: Do you have a good tutorial how to handle this? Thanks (Havent found a good tutorial)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What will happen to the SharedPreferences on update an Android App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637737/what-will-happen-to-the-sharedpreferences-on-update-an-android-app)

Comment: go to developer.android.com. There you can get how to store data on External Storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SharedPreferences will get deleted. But if you use a `BackupAgentHelper` (more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9815641/2829009)), you could back up your preferences to the cloud.

If you want to do it without internet access, you could save your data to the sd-card.