# SharedPreferences for storing an int

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Just a quick question. I need to store one int in my app and SharedPreferences would be a neat and easy way to do it. Any objections to the use of it? Here is my code:

```
private SharedPreferences pref;
private Editor editor;
//-------------------------------
//get the best
pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
editor = pref.edit();
best = pref.getInt("value", 0);
//-------------------------------
//save the best
best = pref.getInt("value", best);
if(best < now){
    editor.putInt("value", now);
    editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this to store:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edt = pref.edit();
edt.putInt("key", i); // i is integer
edt.commit();
```

To use it do:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
int i = pref.getInt("key", -1);
```

Comment: Thanks :) I don't really know how the memory is being used with SharedPreferences. Does the value stay in the memory even after the app is uninstalled? One int is not much but still.

Comment: It is removed when app is uninstalled. But there are ways to store `SharedPreferences`. You can back up to cloud see  http://stackoverflow.com/q/9815363/3879470 : `You should add a BackupAgentHelper to your app. Together with the SharedPreferenceBackupHelper, it backups the SharedPreferences to the cloud (if the device supports it). When the app is reinstalled the data is restored.`

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15873066/3879470 : `When you uninstall any application all the changes the application have made in your internal memory are revoked, that means your SharedPreference files, Other data files, Database file, Application gets removed automatically by the Android OS.`