# Removal of shared preference on update of android application through play store updates or auto updates?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, auto-update

When I update application through popup implemented in application code on change of version shared preference persist but when update using auto-update or from updates available in play store shared preferences got removed?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Simply adding a `?` at the end of a sentence doesn't make it a question - you have to be more specific. Provide code examples, describe your problem and what you've currently done.

Comment: I am trying to show popup in my application when there is version update and give 2 option either to update and skip so when user click on update play store will open and user can update the application and after update  on reopen user got auto login into application due to data(username) persist in shared preference but this doesn't happens when auto-login option is on and when update through updates available in play -store.

Comment: I see. The problem is that SharedPreferences doesn't persist when a user uninstalls (or in your case update then re-install) an application. If you want to persist data outside of the application that persists even after uninstall, you will have to use an external server or service.

Comment: I am wondering about that, usually, by only updating the app through playstore with deinstalling it before, the shared prefeences should persist.

Comment: @marcus... i am only updating the app not reinstalling even in that case not able to find shared preference....but when update through code flow by forcefully deviating user to play store shared preference persist.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [SharedPreferencesBackupHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/SharedPreferencesBackupHelper.html). 
Simply put, it backs up your `SharedPreference` data when ever your app is uninstalled, or when ever you would like to back up your `SharedPreferences`.

Additionally, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815363/in-android-is-there-any-way-to-preserve-sharedpreferences-after-an-uninstall) also addresses your specific problem.

To manually request a restore, you call the `requestRestore()` method. See [this for reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupManager.html#requestRestore(android.app.backup.RestoreObserver)).

> Restore the calling application from backup. The data will be restored
>   from the current backup dataset if the application has stored data
>   there, or from the dataset used during the last full device setup
>   operation if the current backup dataset has no matching data. If no
>   backup data exists for this application in either source, a nonzero
>   value will be returned.

Comment: Yes, you can implement the BackupHelper as you choose. @KaranGarg

Comment: As i found we only need to save the data  and no need to restore so how i will manually call restore when i update app?

Comment: @KaranGarg With the `requestRestore()` method, see the link I included in my answer.

Comment: To use this is it necessary that backup and reset option should be enabled by user?

Comment: I'm sure it's all explained in the links I provided @Karan Garg

Comment: @KaranGarg I could not find that it was necessary, but _if_ one would wish such a behavior, that could easily be implemented as a preference.