# How to save android app user data permanently?

Tags: android, user-data

Is it possible save android app user data to permanent location rather than 'SD card' and server so that when user wife out app data still the data will exist for use?
If possible,
How to do this?

Comment: What will you do with your data if your application doesn't exists anymore ?

Comment: @Shree Krishna If it's a system app than after resting the phone and wiping SD card app will still remain in the system, In that scenario is there any solution for the problem?

Comment: Please look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9815641/4667831). I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @ZaidQureshi Thanks for your link, Actually I wanted to know is to possible without backing up to server or cloud.?